# How can I write this MySQL query in Ruby way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a working MySQL query, which is returning desired value when I pass it in `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. I was wondering how can I write it in more Ruby optimized way.

My Query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT SUM(invoiceAmt) AS invoiceTotal,
       CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(invoiceDate), '(', YEAR(invoiceDate), ')') 
FROM INVOICES 
GROUP BY YEAR(invoiceDate), QUARTER(invoiceDate) 
ORDER BY YEAR(invoiceDate), QUARTER(invoiceDate)
```

Comment: Do you really want to do string concatenation at the database level, or would it suffice to return the correct rows and do the string formatting in application code?

Comment: @vijoc I want to get the correct rows using ruby only. I can format the data later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ActiveRecord` model named `Invoice`, something along these lines should do what you want:

```rb
Invoice.select('SUM(invoiceAmt) AS invoiceTotal, QUARTER(invoiceDate) AS q, YEAR(invoiceDate) AS y')
  .order('y, q')
  .group('y, q')
```

Note that I have not tested the query. The idea here is that you can pass your proven query segments to `#select`, `#order` and `#group`. I used named aliases to simplify the `ORDER` and `GROUP` segments.

Comment: I did something similar previously, but it also returns 'customerId' (which is also a column in Invoice table) as null which I don't want.

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu Are you saying that you would like to select the `customerId` as well, i.e. not have it as null but something else?

Comment: No I don't want `customerId` . Its is also not written in the query you wrote then why it is getting returned?

Comment: Thing is, it is not queried nor returned, which is why it's `null`. I'm assuming you're seeing it in your `Invoice` model, which will list the `customerId` attribute, even if it does not have a value.

Comment: Why only `customerId` is getting returned? Why not other fields which I've not mentioned just like `customerId`? Moreover I'm using returned values to render a JSON output. Any ideas how can I get it right? Does it need formatting or something else?

Comment: For formatting the JSON output, I'd suggest looking into [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu if this answer worked for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), if you don't have an ActiveRecord model for invoices. ActiveRecord uses Arel under the hood, so Rails already has it included

```
invoices = Arel::Table.new(:invoices)
q = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('Q')
open_paren = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('(')
close_paren = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(')')

quarter = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('QUARTER', [invoices[:invoiceDate]])
year = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('YEAR', [invoices[:invoiceDate]])

concatenated = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat', [q, quarter, open_paren, year, close_paren])
query = invoices.
  project(invoices[:invoiceAmt].sum.as('invoiceTotal'), concatenated).
  group(quarter, year).
  order(quarter, year)

puts query.to_sql

# SELECT SUM("invoices"."invoiceAmt") AS invoiceTotal, concat('Q', QUARTER("invoices"."invoiceDate"), '(', YEAR("invoices"."invoiceDate"), ')')
# FROM "invoices"
# GROUP BY QUARTER("invoices"."invoiceDate"), YEAR("invoices"."invoiceDate")
# ORDER BY QUARTER("invoices"."invoiceDate"), YEAR("invoices"."invoiceDate")
```